# Is there a way to create a member variable only when attempted to access in Python?

Tags: python

I have created a simple class that contains a few member variables and methods to explain my question.

```
class cRandomClass:
    def __init__(self, book):
        self.largeTextString = book

        ##self.getSpecificString() will search through the largeTextString variable to get the value 
        self.specificString = self.getSpecificString()


    def getSpecificString(self):
        ##Some code that searches for a string
```

Here "specificString" is created and the return value of "getSpecificString()" is stored, when the object is instantiated since it's in the object constructer.

However, is there a way where I can make sure "self.specificString" is created only when the program attempts to access it

```
randomClass = cRandomClass(book)
##I want to create the member variable when calling it, to trigger a function to return a value
randomClass.specificString
```

I could easily use a member function, (but for certain reasons and in this scenario I would rather not)

```
randomClass.getSpecificString()
```

...where the member function would retrieve the string and set the member variable

In other words, I want to only run "getSpecificString()" when I attempt to access the variable "specificString".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `specificString` a class method and put the `@property` decorator on it. Like this

```
class cRandomClass:
    def __init__(self, book):
        self.largeTextString = book

        ##self.getSpecificString() will search through the largeTextString variable to get the value 


    def getSpecificString(self):
        ##Some code that searches for a string
        return 'string'

    @property   
    def specificString(self):
        return self.getSpecificString()
```

So when you 'access' `cRandomClass.specificString` it will just call `getSpecificString()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @user5423 Glad to help, if this solved your problem please accept it as the answer and possibly upvote it if you're so inclined.

Comment: Just another question, if I attempted to access the specificString variable a second time and I had already set the member variable with the same name, will this re-run the getSpecificString or will it access the self.specificString?

Comment: @user5423 it will re-run `getSpecificString`. you can however add logic so that it doesn't, you just need to check if it has already been set with something like `hasattr(self, 'specificString')`, if `True` return the attribute else return the function